# Adding Image Icon to UWP application how to add?

Tags: uwp

I am trying to add icon in UWP application but not sure which file I would need to change , someone please help

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft documentation describes it pretty good. Take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/app-icons-and-logos